# Headphone sudden loud noise on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

When I'm using my headphones and listening or watching something on any browser at some point a loud noise starts to sound. This is not happening only while I use a browser, it happens too while using VLC Player or other applications. But mostly happens with a browser.
The audio starts normal but a few seconds/minutes later the audio is distorted and a loud noise starts and doesn't stops until I pause the audio for a while.

I recorded this. I leave a link to a sample:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kVkIJ0ZWz4mcABtbNyMLrZ8JMFRS5FrV/view?usp=sharing

This started after a recently fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04. Started using Unity desktop and switched to Mate desktop a few hours later.
I can't confirm if this happened while using Unity because I didn't used my headphones back then. I can't confirm either if this happens with speakers because I don't have any to do the test.
This doesn't happen when I'm using Windows 10 on the same computer.
All drivers are up to date and tried purging Pulse Audio, Alsa and reinstalling and rebooting.

I've tried other solutions in other posts but none seem to work all most of them have a similar issue but not exactly my issue.

Pulse Audio dump:

```
### Read from configuration file: /etc/pulse/daemon.conf ###
daemonize = no
fail = yes
high-priority = yes
nice-level = -11
realtime-scheduling = yes
realtime-priority = 5
allow-module-loading = yes
allow-exit = yes
use-pid-file = yes
system-instance = no
local-server-type = user
cpu-limit = no
enable-shm = yes
flat-volumes = no
rescue-streams = yes
lock-memory = no
exit-idle-time = 20
scache-idle-time = 20
dl-search-path = /usr/lib/pulse-13.99.1/modules
default-script-file = /etc/pulse/default.pa
load-default-script-file = yes
log-target = 
log-level = notice
resample-method = auto
avoid-resampling = no
enable-remixing = yes
remixing-use-all-sink-channels = yes
remixing-produce-lfe = no
remixing-consume-lfe = no
lfe-crossover-freq = 0
default-sample-format = s16le
default-sample-rate = 44100
alternate-sample-rate = 48000
default-sample-channels = 2
default-channel-map = front-left,front-right
default-fragments = 4
default-fragment-size-msec = 25
enable-deferred-volume = yes
deferred-volume-safety-margin-usec = 1
deferred-volume-extra-delay-usec = 0
shm-size-bytes = 0
log-meta = no
log-time = no
log-backtrace = 0
rlimit-fsize = -1
rlimit-data = -1
rlimit-stack = -1
rlimit-core = -1
rlimit-rss = -1
rlimit-as = -1
rlimit-nproc = -1
rlimit-nofile = 256
rlimit-memlock = -1
rlimit-locks = -1
rlimit-sigpending = -1
rlimit-msgqueue = -1
rlimit-nice = 31
rlimit-rtprio = 9
rlimit-rttime = 200000
```

Comment: Same issue here. I did notice that the "loud noise" is really just extreme overamplification that starts seconds/minutes into a video. If I manually go to Settings -> Sound after the noise starts, I can turn down the volume manually and the sound is almost normal. Of course, the same thing just happens again next time. However, this does not happen to me in Chrome; only in VLC etc. Earlier versions of Ubuntu did not have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the sudden, extreme overamplification begins seconds/minutes into videos, but this seems to help:

1. In /etc/pulse/daemon.conf, change `; default-sample-rate = 44100` to `default-sample-rate = 48000` (uncomment and change value)
2. `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio` (**not** as root)
3. `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol` (PulseAudio Volume Control)
4. Start pavucontrol from menu or command line
5. In my case, my desired device is USB Audio. In the Configuration tab, I set it to "Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output".
6. In the Output Devices tab, for USB Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958), I selected "Port: Digital Output (S/PDIF)" from the drop-down menu.
7. In the Output Devices tab, use the slider to **lower the volume** of the device to around 20% or so. This is key.
8. Use the volume control of your external amplifier etc to turn up the sound as needed. You can also carefully/slowly turn up the volume on the slider if needed.
9. During the setup process, keep the slider volume low and the extreme overamplification should never kick in. But leave the pavucontrol window open. If the noise does kick in, let it continue but lower the volume slider until it becomes a clean sound.

So far so good but it's only been a few days.

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu 22.04 and windows 10 are installed on the laptop

1. In windows 10, the built-in speaker and the headset are normal
2. The built-in speaker in ubuntu22.04 runs normally, but the earphone hums

I encountered two situations and fixed them in the following way:

Case 1:

When the headphones are plugged in, a buzzing sound occurs, regardless of whether music or video is playing

Case 2:

When the headphones are plugged in, there is a buzzing sound in the background only when playing music and videos

Fix:

> root permission run command: "alsamixer", press the arrow key "→",
> find the "auto-mute mode" option, then press "↑ ", set to "Enabled",
> press "Esc" to exit, then try to fix the problem.

PS:

If you want to enter power saving mode, only play whether to start the sound card.
Run the command:

```
cat /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

If the value is "0", the power saving mode is displayed. If the value is "1", run the following command to change the value to 0:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```